# Upper div background with body background

Tags: html, css

I have in my project a really beautiful image as body background.
Then, i add different layer of div on it.

But then, on one of my upper div, i would like to have the body background image as background of my upper div. Excatly as it is under it.

Is it possible ?

```
<html>
  <body style="background: url('my MAGNIFICIENT IMAGE');">
    <div style="background-color: black;">
      <div style="background-color: orange;">
        <div style="**background: THE BODY ONE (my MAGNIFICIENT IMAGE ???**">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
body {
  background: center / cover url("https://www.thespruce.com/thmb/BEHApXGrqTAcKxnnKjbXYw6gj4Q=/2121x1193/smart/filters:no_upscale()/zen-garden-w-plants-big-5c130a6946e0fb0001f8f0dd.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#one, #two {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

#one {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
}

#two {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 60vw;
}

#overlay {
  background: center / cover url("https://www.thespruce.com/thmb/BEHApXGrqTAcKxnnKjbXYw6gj4Q=/2121x1193/smart/filters:no_upscale()/zen-garden-w-plants-big-5c130a6946e0fb0001f8f0dd.jpg") no-repeat fixed;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 40vw;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="background-color: black;" id="one">
      <div style="background-color: orange;" id="two">
        <div id="overlay"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the same magnificient image as in your body and set `background-attachment: fixed;`. Eventually you have to adjust the `background-position` as well.